# Difference in LinkedList, queue vs list

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list, queue

What is the difference when creating these two objects

```
Queue<String> test = new LinkedList<String>();
```

and

```
List<String> test2 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

What are the actual differences between `test` and `test2`? Are both of them `LinkedList` ?  Are there performance differences or reasons to use one over the other?

Comment: @BheshGurung- Are you sure?  I'm pretty sure both of these are legal Java code.

Comment: They don't compile because they're missing a (), not because the assignment would be illegal :)

Comment: ok () has been corrected

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The two statements you've written each construct a `LinkedList<String>` object to hold a list of strings, then assign it to a variable.  The difference is in the type of the variable.

By assigning the `LinkedList<String>` to a variable of type `Queue<String>`, you can only access the methods in the `LinkedList` that are available in the `Queue<String>` interface, which includes support for enqueuing and dequeuing elements.  This would be useful if you needed to write a program that used a queue for various operations and wanted to implement that queue by using a linked list.

By assigning the `LinkedList<String>` to a variable of type `List<String>`, you can only access the methods in the `LinkedList` that are available in the `List<String>` interface, which are normal operations for maintaining a sequence of elements.  This would be useful, for example, if you needed to process a list of elements that could grow and shrink anywhere.

In short, the two lines create the same object but intend to use them in different ways.  One says that it needs a queue backed by a linked list, while the other says that it needs a general sequence of elements backed by a linked list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

In the both the cases, you are instantiating `LinkedList`.

The difference is the types of the variables you use to refer to those instances.

`test` is of type `Queue` and `test2` is of type `List`. Depending on the type of variable, you only get to invoke the methods which are specified on that particular type. I think this what matters for your situation.

Performance-wise, it's going to be the same, because the actual implementation that you are using in both the cases is same (`LinkedList`).

Answer (score 3):

I feel both of them are pretty much same except that the type of methods you are going to expose. As LinkedList implements both the interfaces, so choosing one of them opens up access to methods of that interface type.

please take a look at these links for interface method declarations

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

i am not sure about the performance, though i guess it shouldn't be different as the object implementation is common.