# Same method invocations, different result in LinkedList, Queue vs. List

Tags: java, list, linked-list, queue

I have read the thread [Difference in LinkedList, queue vs list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608026/difference-in-linkedlist-queue-vs-list), but still don't understand the following code behavior:

```
List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
l.add(10);
l.add(12);
l.remove(1); // removes index 1
System.out.println(l); // outputs [10]
    
Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<>();
q2.add(10);
q2.add(12);
q2.remove(1); // tries to remove object 1
System.out.println(q2); // outputs [10, 12]
```

I know, why the outputs differ:

- in case of `l` the call `remove(1)` removes the element with the index `1`
- in case of `q` the call `remove(1)` tries to remove an object `1`, but there are only Integers `10` and `12`.

If I take a closer look to the interfaces:

- [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) does not have a `remove(int)` method, but inherits a `remove(Object)` method from [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).
- [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has a `remove(int index)` and `remove(Object o)` method.

So far, so good.

But: I do not understand, how Java is able to invoke two different methods while using the same syntax (`remove(1)`)?

Comment: Yes. Avoid auto-boxing/unboxing whenever possible. Enable compiler warnings for that, in your IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `l` is of type `List`, which has two `remove` methods: `remove(Object)` inherited from `Collection` and `remove(int)` defined for `List`. A call to `remove(1)`is linked to `remove(int)` because that's an exact match.
`q2`on the other hand is a `Queue` and this type does not specify `remove(int)`. Only `remove(Object)` from `Collection`. So the compiler generates autoboxing from `int` to `Integer` and links the call to `remove(Object)`.

What may be confusing: q2 in fact holds a `List`. But that doesn't matter. The compiler only "see's" the type of the variable referencing the Object. The real type of the Object is ignored (in fact unknown in most cases).
Knowing q2 holds a `List`you could do a type cast:

```
((List<Integer>)q2).remove(1);
```

This would again lead to a call to `List.remove(int)` because the compiler then knows the object you're dealing with is a `List`

Answer (score 6):

For `List`, the compiler chooses `remove(int)` according to the [method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> The process of determining applicability begins by determining the potentially applicable methods (§15.12.2.1). Then, to ensure compatibility with the Java programming language prior to Java SE 5.0, the process continues in three phases:

> 1. The first phase performs overload resolution ***without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion***, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

Note the emphasized part, which means the compiler matches `1` with an `int`. Since there is an applicable method `remove(int)`, that is the one chosen for invocation. In other words, the primitive type is considered first, before considering reference types such as `Integer` (the boxed type for `int`).

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the calling code. With

```
l.remove(1);
```

you are using an `int` as a parameter on a generic data structure that was declared with `Integer` as the type parameter. This works for queues also  because of the automatic boxing behavior in Java.

If you use an `Integer` then both calls behave the same:

```
l.remove(Integer.valueOf(1));
q2.remove(Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Now both calls remove the desired *object*.

Answer (score -2):

The implementations of both methods are different -- since a Queue only allows removal from the bottom and the top of the stack, you'll have to use the specific methods for both removal methods, versus a List which is meant for index operators.

In this case, Queue overrides `remove(Object obj)` to remove the object itself, versus list, which overrides `remove(Object obj)` and adds an extra `remove(int index)` to allow index and object removal.